# Combining strings

Tags: python

Let's say I have 2 lists of strings, and I want to make a new list by combining the two lists so that the first string in the first list, will be in a tuple with the first word in the second list, second with second and so on...

Just for example:

```
input: lst1 = ["hello", "first", "is"]
input: lst2 = ["my", "name", "tom"]
output: [("hello","my"), ("first", "name"), ("is", "tom")]
```

I wrote something like that:

```
lst1 = ["hello", "first", "is"]
lst2 = ["my", "name", "tom"]
new_list = []
    for i in lst1 :
            for j in lst2 :
                    two_words = (i, j)
                    new_list.append(two_words)
    return new_list
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julio's answer is in fact the pythonic way of doing it. But as to your question what you're doing wrong, your error is here:

```
    for i in lst1 :
            for j in lst2 :
```

You don't want to iterate over the lists like that, because you only want a result that is the same size as both lists. Assuming both lists are the same size, it would simply be

```
lst1 = ["hello", "first", "is"]
lst2 = ["my", "name", "tom"]
new_list = []
    for i in range(len(lst1)):
                    new_list.append((lst1[i], list2[i]))
    return new_list
```

Comment: I tried it but it says: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @user1073865 the problem is you're trying to iterate this: `len(lst1)` (a int). Change it for: `range(len(lst1))`.

Answer (score 6):

`zip` is what you're looking for:

```
>>> lst1 = ["hello", "first", "is"]
>>> lst2 = ["my", "name", "tom"]
>>> zip(lst1,lst2)
[('hello', 'my'), ('first', 'name'), ('is', 'tom')]
```

More about it: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that a loop inside a loop forms a "cross product", creating every possible pair of strings from the two lists.  The solution is to use `zip`, or to make a single loop over the possible indices.

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way to do it using  list comprehensions.

```
lst1 = ["hello", "first", "is"]
lst2 = ["my", "name", "tom"]
new_list = [ ( lst1[i], lst2[i] ) for i in range ( len(lst1) ) ]
```

if you want the inner elements to be in a list,
use

```
new_list = [ [ lst1[i], lst2[i] ] for i in range ( len(lst1) ) ]
```

output:

```
[('hello', 'my'), ('first', 'name'), ('is', 'tom')]
```